# Using multiple columns in a single Form combo-box as query parameters in MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have a form with a combo-box that holds two columns from a Table. I would like to use the two fields from a selected row in that combo box as the parameters for a query.

i.e. combo box has `WANTED` and `UNWANTED` columns and I want the query to

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE people LIKE "WANTED FROM COMBO BOX" AND people NOT LIKE "UNWANTED FROM COMBO BOX"`

I can only seem to get this to work with the bound column of the combo box. I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE people LIKE [Forms]![formName]![comboBoxName].column(0) 
AND people NOT LIKE [Forms]![formName]![comboBoxName].column(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to *bind* a textbox on the form to the other column of the combobox.

Or use an unbound textbox you assign the value of the other column from the *AfterUpdate* event of the combobox.

Then refer to that textbox in your query.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be a cleaner way to do it. I will try that.